# Confusion about iterator in python

Tags: python, iterator

I am confused about iterator in python. Please take a look on the code.

```py
class MyNumbers:
  def __init__(self):
     self.a=4
  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    if self.a <= 20:
      x = self.a
      self.a += 1
      return x
    else:
      raise StopIteration

myclass = MyNumbers()
myiter1 = iter(myclass)
c=list(myiter1)
for x in myiter1:
  print(x)
```

I getting no output from the above code. I was expecting some value iteration from 4.
but when i was removing `c=list(myiter1)` i was getting expected output. So i am confused about it. why is it happening.

Comment: `y=self.b` it where is b defined?

Comment: by `c=list(myiter1)` you are already exhausting the iterator, that is why the loop not working. Check by `next(myiter1)` it should throw `StopIteration` exception after `list(myiter1)`, which means it is exhausted.

Comment: If you remove line `c=list(myiter1)` then the loop prints the values in the iterator

Comment: while editing the code i forget to remove `y=self.b`. What does it meant by exhausting the iterator @Epsi95

Comment: If want creation of iterator to reset itself each time then add `self.a = 4` to __iter__ function.

Comment: One thing to mention that you are wrongly applying `iter()` on `myclass`. A class that implements both `__iter__` and `__next__` is an `iterator`, so you can directly loop through it.  But it not necessarily the case, `iter()` is called on `iterable` to get iterator` For example `list` is an iterable, so you can't do `next()` on list directly, you need to get the iterator by `iter(your_list)`. `list(something)`, `for in something` calls `iter(something` under the hood

Answer (score 2):

Your iterator is exhausted: `list` in the assignment to `c` consumed all the available values, resulting in a list `[4, 5, 6, ..., 20]` and an iterator that will raise `StopIteration` immediately when you try to iterate over it again.

You may be confused because it appears you can iterate over a list multiple times. But that is because a list itself is *not* an iterator.

```
>>> list.__next__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute '__next__'
```

Calling `iter` on a list produces a `list_iterator` value, not the list itself. That iterator is exhaustible like any other iterator.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = iter(x)
>>> type(y)
<class 'list_iterator'>
>>> list(y)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(y)
[]
```

The `for` loop implicitly calls `iter` on the thing you are try to iterate over. By convention, all iterators are also iterable: an iterator's `__iter__` should return `self`.